# flutter: how to prevent expandable TextField's inner scroll when there is ListView scroll available

Tags: flutter, listview, widget

Trying to implement the expandable TextField() in ListView(). The page should have one `scrollController` on the `ListView()`. If I add text, it should expand the widget with multiline but when I click on the Text it should scroll the entire ListView() rather than keep scrolling inside the TextField().

The Expected Result is here as a video (from Instagram post creation): https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOBwy.jpg

I tried while disabling the `physics` then not able to bring the cursor to the desired position.
[image]

Comment: can you share your code as well? and also share what you are getting?

Comment: @Diwyansh Sure for that. give me a moment I'll upload the result accordingly shortly

Comment: sure, let me know once done.

Comment: Hi, @Diwyansh I have resolved the issue while replacing the TextField() with TextFormField(). Thanks a lot